# Список тем из thread_list в thread_view из раздела в котором сама тема Xenforo

Tags: php, шаблоны, форум

Возникла проблема: очень плохо понимаю php и структуру обработки шаблонов Xenforo. Пытался подключить с помощью такого вида:

```
<xen:hook name="thread_list_threads">
    <xen:foreach loop="$threads" value="$thread">
        <xen:include template="thread_list_item" />
    </xen:foreach>
</xen:hook>
```

Но не получилось. Пишет: "Пока что нет не одной темы". Как ни пытался, не выходит. Как понимаю нужно как-то организовать, чтоб он подгружал по айди раздела, в котором тема. Хочется такую же фишку как у Flarum организовать, но похоже средствами самого шаблона не получится. Чисто для примера, для образца, ссылка на фларум, где есть боковая выезжающая шторка, на которой как раз список тем из раздела, в котором находится пользователь в данный момент.

[image: Пример]

[image: Пример при наведении]

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение в плагине Similar Threads он полностью решает поставленную задачу может кому либо пригодится [Сам плагин](http://www.xf-russia.ru/forum/threads/similar-threads.8152/)

Две недели поисков и решение найдено )